# Matching widths of elements with dynamic content along a row using css only

Tags: css, flexbox

I have been attempting to use flexbox for this, but any other css-only solution would be acceptable.

I want all items along a row to expand to the width of the largest item, so the result is identical widths. However, at the same time without the parent element expanding beyond the minimum size needed to accomplish this.

If you look at my Codepen example, altering the flex-grow value on `<ul>` elements will make this work for some of the demo examples, but not all.

http://codepen.io/MattyBalaam/pen/VepxWq

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 0 2em;
  flex-grow: 0.15;    
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2em;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>----3----</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty sure what you are asking is not possible with CSS,,,because that's not *exactly how flex-grow works: https://css-tricks.com/flex-grow-is-weird/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Every item to have the same width as the widest element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31159732/1529630)