# Is there a way to make CSS table-cell divs have equal widths?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, tablecell

Right now, I have a set of columns that are styled as `display: table-cell` in CSS. Each column has a `min-width` of 280px and a `max-width` of 360px. The only issue is that I want these columns to be equally-sized. That is, I want the columns to each be as wide as the widest column. I could probably write some javascript that could do this. Is there a way to do this with just CSS though?

I could maybe also use flexbox if that would be any better.

Comment: is this: https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/ what you want?

Comment: Well, except that's fluid width, equal height. I want fluid height, equal width.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31159732/every-item-to-have-the-same-width-as-the-widest-element I think this will answer your question and give you some code too.

Comment: I would advise using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

Comment: You must have been around long enough to know how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Is this works as you expected ?

```css
.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.column {
  min-width: 280px;
  max-width: 360px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">bla bla bla</div>
    <div class="cell">bla bla blabla bla bla</div>
    <div class="cell">bla bla bla</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">bla bla bla</div>
    <div class="cell">bla bla blabla bla bla</div>
    <div class="cell">bla bla bla</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">bla bla blabla bla blabla bla bla</div>
    <div class="cell">bla bla bla</div>
    <div class="cell">bla bla bla</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.