# Set all li element's width, to the one that has the largest width

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I have a list of elements of varying content sizes like so:

```
<ul class="list-group ul-right">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <b> Name</b>         
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <b> Longer Name</b>         
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <b> Longest Name in the World </b>         
    </li>
<ul>
```

I want the li elements to all have the same width, and that width to be determined by the one that has the longest content. I've seen that I can use **display: inline-block**; to adjust the li element's width based on it's content, but I don't want them all to have different widths, but instead for each of them to share the width of the one that has largest content. How can I do this using html5, css, and/or bootstrap?

Comment: and by "size" you mean width or height?

Comment: By size I mean width, I'll edit that

Comment: without the css it's impossible to know what you have so far and what affect your html structue. Add a jsfiddle/codepen/snippet that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ok, I'll make one and edit the question again.

Comment: I already figured out the problem, the problem was that my bootstrap grid was 5 columns wide and that didn't allow the elements to increase their width past that, so I increased the height of each element and settled for the information being displayed in 2 consecutive lines.

Comment: This is why I said that without the css it's impossible to know... next time create a jsfiddle that show exactly your problem and it will be much easier to help.

Comment: Sadly I couldn't show the code through the use of jsfiddle or codepen because, they apparently omit bootstrap code.

Comment: There is no problem as all to use bootstrap in jsfiddle & codepen

Comment: Then it must have been something else, thanks for the help anyways guys :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Every item to have the same width as the widest element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31159732/every-item-to-have-the-same-width-as-the-widest-element)

Answer (score 2):

inline-block is a good start, but for ul :

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
li {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group ul-right">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <b> Name</b> 
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <b> Longer Name</b> 
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <b> Longest Name in the World </b> 
  </li>
  </ul>
    hi !
```

table can do if you want to keep the block behavior.

```css
ul {
  display: table;
}
li {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group ul-right">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <b> Name</b> 
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <b> Longer Name</b> 
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <b> Longest Name in the World </b> 
  </li>
</ul>
hi !
```

Float does too :

```css
ul {
  float:left;
}
li {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group ul-right">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <b> Name</b> 
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <b> Longer Name</b> 
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <b> Longest Name in the World </b> 
  </li>
</ul>
hi !
```

Comment: Putting inline-block on the ul was the solution for me

Answer (score 1):

With `flexbox` you can achieve that. `display: inline-flex;` work as `display: inline-block`, size's itself based on content. The `flex: 1` on the flex item make them all fill the remaining space and will therefore be come equal width

```css
.list-group {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.list-group-item {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group ul-right">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <b> Name</b>         
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <b> Longer Name</b>         
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <b> Longest Name in the World </b>         
    </li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end of 2018, I found and used a cool feature:

https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content

```
ul.list-group {
  width: max-content;
}
```

Please try.