# set div width according to largest div

Tags: css, width

I have a group of 5 `div`s, all with auto width.

The text will be inserted dynamically into each div and I want to change all `div`s width to the largest of the 5.

Any ideas?

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Hi</div>
<div class="box">Hi John</div>
<div class="box">Hello John</div>
<div class="box">Hello John Doe</div>
```

I think I should be using JS, but I'm wondering if it's possible to avoid it.

Comment: Imagine it, they'll change. Otherwise, provide us with some code you've written so that we can see and understand rather than imagine.

Comment: Please include a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the code that you have already tried yourself. This isn't a coding or tutoring service. Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and the relevant code. See: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ... probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656183/how-to-set-flex-items-to-equal-width-according-to-the-item-with-the-longest-cont/42659167 unless you want to stack them ...

Comment: @G-Cyr good question. Now that you ask, both situations :)

Comment: both situations ? media querie maybe ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dVWEpe please clarify the question ... amount of box per rows, when should it wrap into columns only if that is the both situation you mean, ....

Answer (score 0):

I would use javascript:

```
function setWidth(e,w) {
    e.setAttribute("style","width:"+ w +"px");
    e.style.width= w +'px';
}
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
var max = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    var width = boxes[i].clientWidth;
    if (width > max) max = width;
}
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    setWidth(boxes[i],max);
}
```