# Is there a way to only use CSS in order to make a button have the same width as a sibling button?

Tags: html, css

Basically, I have two *buttons* that have the same style and are lined beside each other inside a parent *div*.

```
<div style="text-align: center">
  <button class="btn btn-primary button1">Button1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary button2">Button2</button>
</div>



.btn {
  min-height: 44px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 320px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 6px 24px
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;

  &.btn-primary {
    border: none;
    background-color: #808080;
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }

  &.button1{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
  }

  &.button2{
    margin-left: 12px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 6px 36px;
  }
}
```

Because the second button is translated in lots of languages, its width is set to **auto**. The problem here is that the first button must have the same dynamic width as the second one at all times.

So, is there a way to achieve this condition on the first button by only using CSS? Keep in mind that the buttons are lined on the same row.

Comment: This is not possible to do dynamically using CSS. You can't get the width of one element and apply it to another with CSS. You can use JS or you can simply set the buttons to have the same static width regardless of content.

Comment: @AlainCruz the buttons are lined on the same row not like in that duplicate question

Comment: probably a duplicate if grid, flex or column would be involved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656183/how-to-set-flex-items-to-equal-width-according-to-the-item-with-the-longest-cont/42659167#42659167

Comment: @AlainCruz I would really like to see how you can achieve the same. If you do I will close the question as duplicate (I have a gold badge)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS grid can do this:

```css
 body {
  text-align: center
 }
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  margin:10px;
}

.btn {
  min-height: 44px;
  max-width: 320px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 6px 24px border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-primary {
  border: none;
  background-color: #808080;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
}

.button2 {
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 6px 36px;
}
```

```html
<div  class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-primary button1">Button1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary button2">Button2</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-primary button1">Button1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary button2">Button with long text</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-primary button1">Button1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary button2">Button text</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you could also use flex

```css
div {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.btn {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 44px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 320px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 6px 24px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn.btn-primary {
  border: none;
  background-color: #808080;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.btn.button1 {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
  flex-shrink: 0 !important;
}
.btn.button2 {
  margin-left: 12px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 6px 36px;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
  <button class="btn btn-primary button1">Button1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary button2">Button2</button>
</div>
```

You may also use column CSS

```css
div {
  column-count:2;
  width:max-content;
  margin:auto;
}

.btn {
  min-height: 44px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 320px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 6px 24px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn.btn-primary {
  border: none;
  background-color: #808080;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.btn.button1 {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
  flex-shrink: 0 !important;
}
.btn.button2 {
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 6px 36px;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
  <button class="btn btn-primary button1">Button1 longer </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary button2">Button2</button>
</div>
```