# CSS: List items of equal width (of the widest element in list)

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Is it possible to make all list items equally wide according to list's widest item? See the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/82m71ztw/2/

```
<ol class="progress">
    <li class="active">First step: Choose</li>
    <li>Step two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: You can try to do it using on `.progress { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); grid-gap: 0 10px; }`. In this case you can make your `li` same size + responsive. The only problem is that they are **not sported on IE**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Every item to have the same width as the widest element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31159732/every-item-to-have-the-same-width-as-the-widest-element)

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript to calculate width of each list, add them to an array, select max value and assign it to each list. The following code is tested and works great:

```
var lists = document.querySelectorAll(".progress li");
var arrayList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
   var eachList = lists[i].offsetWidth;
   arrayList.push(eachList);
   var MaxWidth = Math.max.apply(null, arrayList);
   lists[i].style.width = MaxWidth +"px";

}
```

Here is a jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rowin_aria/2szow6rb/2/

its not css, however few lines of JS will save you scratching your head plus this gives you an accurate result

Answer (score 0):

Shah's solution didn't quite do it for me. Each width was set to that of the widest element above it.  I changed his code to make two loops. The first gathers all the widths and the second sets the width of each element to that of the widest one.

```
var lists = document.querySelectorAll(".progress li");
var arrayList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
   var eachList = lists[i].offsetWidth;
   arrayList.push(eachList);
}
var MaxWidth = Math.max.apply(null, arrayList);
for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
   lists[i].style.width = MaxWidth +"px";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your css just add a fixed width, depending on the largest li element.`

```
li {
        list-style-type: none;
        counter-increment: item;
        width: 163px;
.....`
```

Comment: that's only assuming you know the elements width earlier

Comment: Yeah true, in this case it is known though. Not mentioned otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a `flexbox` for the list and let the items grow. See https://jsfiddle.net/82m71ztw/75/