# Flex items don't have the same width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Basically, I'm trying to make all blue boxes the same width and height regardless of the content inside them. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```css
.icon-tiles {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
      justify-content: space-around;
}

.tile-node {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 33.33333%;
          flex: 1 33.33333%;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.tile-node__content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}


.tile-node__link {
  background-color: #4d8acc;
  padding: 2rem;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="icon-tiles">
    <li class="tile-node">
        <a href="#" class="tile-node__link">
            <div class="tile-node__content tile-node__content--calendar">
                <span class="tile-node__text">My Link One</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tile-node">
        <a href="#" class="tile-node__link">
            <div class="tile-node__content tile-node__content--bus">
                <span class="tile-node__text">Link two</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tile-node">
        <a href="#" class="tile-node__link">
            <div class="tile-node__content tile-node__content--map">
                <span class="tile-node__text">Another link</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tile-node">
        <a href="#" class="tile-node__link">
            <div class="tile-node__content tile-node__content--essentials">
                <span class="tile-node__text">Another one</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tile-node">
        <a href="#" class="tile-node__link">
            <div class="tile-node__content tile-node__content--reminder">
                <span class="tile-node__text">New link twooooo</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tile-node">
        <a href="#" class="tile-node__link">
            <div class="tile-node__content tile-node__content--book">
                <span class="tile-node__text">Link three</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why don't you just add a width to .tile-node?

Comment: I don't want them to be restricted by a width as the content will be dynamically added.

Comment: please focus on the problem instead of telling your personnal story ... we simply need details about your issue not yourself

Comment: I am afraid that it's not possible with pure CSS, as flex-items are not aware of their siblings' size. You can use JS to achieve this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31159732/every-item-to-have-the-same-width-as-the-widest-element

Comment: All blue boxes of same width and height where content will be dynamically added? Try this in your `script` tag. Add `onChange` listener for all elements, make a common function which compares width of all ` elements` and thereafter changes the width accordingly `onChange`

Comment: All of your current HTML & CSS can be split in half.

Comment: Thanks Michael_B for the explanation - that does make a lot of sense!

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work for you, please check demo snippet

```css
.icon-tiles {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
      justify-content: space-around;
}

.tile-node {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 33.33333%;
          flex: 1 33.33333%;

  padding: 2rem;
}

.tile-node__content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}


.tile-node__link {
background-color: #4d8acc;
padding: 10px;
/* flex: 1; */
height: 84px;
overflow: hidden;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul class="icon-tiles">
    <li class="tile-node">
        <a href="#" class="tile-node__link">
            <div class="tile-node__content tile-node__content--calendar">
                <span class="tile-node__text">My Link One My Link One My Link One My Link One</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tile-node">
        <a href="#" class="tile-node__link">
            <div class="tile-node__content tile-node__content--bus">
                <span class="tile-node__text">Link two</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tile-node">
        <a href="#" class="tile-node__link">
            <div class="tile-node__content tile-node__content--map">
                <span class="tile-node__text">Another link</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tile-node">
        <a href="#" class="tile-node__link">
            <div class="tile-node__content tile-node__content--essentials">
                <span class="tile-node__text">Another one</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tile-node">
        <a href="#" class="tile-node__link">
            <div class="tile-node__content tile-node__content--reminder">
                <span class="tile-node__text">New link twooooo</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tile-node">
        <a href="#" class="tile-node__link">
            <div class="tile-node__content tile-node__content--book">
                <span class="tile-node__text">Link three</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you also explain what changes have you made? and why?

Comment: Thanks for this Rahul, but the problem is that I don't want the outer box to have the same width as the anchor tag.

Answer (score -1):

Just add the following to your CSS class `.tile-node__link` and it will work as given below:

```
.tile-node__link {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 6rem;
}
```

and remove `padding: 2rem` from this class.

I hope this was helpful.